# MSB3644 on the build server after upgrading to .NET 5

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-5

Today I updated VS2019 to ver. 16.8 (both on my development machines and on the build server) and I retargeted my projects from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5.
Everything works on the two machines I use for development.  I checked in the changes and it now doesn't build on the build server reporting the following error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1180,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v5.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application.`

I can't find any reference assemblies for .NET 5 in C:\Program Files (x86)\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft, but they don't exist on my development machines either.

.NET 5 is clearly installed on the build server (I verified it with "dotnet --info").
MSBuild ver. 16.8.1.52902 is in use.  VS2019 ver. 16.8 is installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you run dotnet --info from the build folder on the build server? A global.json file can override which version of the SDK it will attempt to use. (https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/02/17/developing-two-versions-net-core-sdk-side-side/). And it's anywhere in the path to the build folder (Including the project folder itself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who experience the same issue:

Installing C# project templates solved the problem!